# Setting DatePickerDialog to allow dates before the year 1900

Tags: java, android, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I'm building birthday guessing game that accepts user input dates from a DatePickerDialog box that pops up when the user touches a textView box. The only problem is that the minimum date allowed is the first of the year 1900. I need to be able to access dates from the year 1700. Is there any way to adjust the minimum date displayed in the DatePickerDialog.

This is what I have in my main.java file

```
//Date Bar initial display (will display current date)
    mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(GuessMaster.this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                    mDateSetListener, year, month, day);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();



        }
    });

    //Date Bar Input Listener
    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            month+=1;// now will treat january as 1 instead of 0
            String date = month+"/"+dayOfMonth+"/"+year;
            mDisplayDate.setText(date);

            Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet:"+year+"/"+month+"/"+dayOfMonth);

        }
```

Thank you

Comment: You’ve probably already looked at [the `minDate` XML attribute of `DatePicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#attr_android:minDate)? What happens if you set it to `01/01/1700`?

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

`dialog.getDatePicker().updateDate(year,month,day);`

Comment: StackOverflow aims to get high quality answers to questions, so that they can be a long term help to the community. Please edit your answer to add extra explanations and details. See [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [How do I format my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). For instance, put 4 spaces in front of your code snippets to make them look like `code`.